# Cannot redeclare class using array for the classes names

Tags: php, class

I have an array of classes:

```
$array_items = [
    'User\Name',
    'Item\Name'
];
```

I need to execute a method from each one of them like:

```
foreach ($array_items as $class)
    (new $class)->get();
endforeach;
```

But this way it throws an error "Cannot redeclare class User/Name" and that's it.

If I try this, it's ok (but of course it outputs the User/Name twice):

```
foreach ($array_items as $class)
    (new \User\Name)->get();
endforeach;
```

Any ideas why it's happening, or workarounds?

Comment: Do you need to declare the class names as part of an array? Why not just use them directly?

Comment: It sounds like there might be a bug in your autoloader.

Answer (score 1):

If your classes are being defined when you use `new` to create an instance of them, then it means that the code for the class is being loaded by a PHP "autoloader".

If you're getting errors defining a class when you do `new`, then it means you have a bug in your autoloader.

In this case, the error message is implying that when you do `new Item\Name`, the autoloader is incorrectly opening the file for the `User\Name` class. When this file is opened, PHP tries to run it, and throws the error because the class within has already been defined.

You haven't given us your autoloader code, so I can't give you an exact fix, but the solution will be to modify the code where it tries to locate the class file to ensure that it loads the correct file.

If your program's file structure and your autoloader are written to conform to the PSR standards, then this issue will not occur. The PSR standards state that files for classes should be organised such that their folder structure matches the namespaces. This makes it easy to write an autoloader that always finds the correct file. Many such autoloaders exist, and indeed, if you use the Composer tool for your third-party libraries, then it also provides a PSR compliant autoloader for your application, so you don't need to write your own.